# Redo-shortcut vanished - eclipse on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-juno

For quite a while my Eclipse Juno won't let my redo my undo's via shortcuts, although the binding is set properly and I didn't change a thing. You can see there's something wrong here as the shortcut isn't even listed anymore.[image: I lost my shortcut :(]
That's how it's set in the settings:
[image: binding is set]

Did anybody encounter the same problem? I have the problem at 32 and 64bit Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, Build 20130225-0426 on OSX 10.8.3, but I think it was already there back with 10.8.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you describe your **redo** key configurations like below, your problem will be solved.

[image: Eclipse Keys Config]

Comment: I just tested to add one of those and it began to work again, but I really wonder why there's no global way to define it for all editors.

Comment: I have 2 mac mini and one mac pro at my office. There is no problem with mac book pro and another mac mini. I don't know why I have problem with current mac mini with eclipse juno. I tried various key combination, I choose editing java source it only allows java sources. I added different combinations with different when states so it solved :p

Comment: Yeah same with latest version Kepler - on laptop it's good, but on desktop redo doesn't work - adding this for "Editing Java Source" fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

vtokmak's answer seems to be working for most, but it's probably worth noting that for some other users, the problem may be conflicting key bindings. You can check/rule this out by searching for the binding your shortcut *ought* to be (e.g. "Shift+Ctrl+Z". Be careful of order).

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem. A plugin (JADclipse decompiler) had bound itself to Shift+Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Same for the angular plugin, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you install eclipse plugins they occasionally mess up with your key bindings. You should **look** for **'Shift+Command+Z'** by **sorting the 'Binding' column**, as it is not searchable. If you find more than one key bindings, then **you should only keep one global key binding**, as per the below image.

The '*Redo*' command, with '*When*' set as **'In Dialogs and Windows'** is the **only one global option** people should have.

[image]